# How do I find the intersections of 2 circles on earths surface?

Tags: circles

I have the circles' center in lat & long, as well as the radius in meters. How do I find the circles intersections?

Edit: EXAMPLE:

```
Circle 1: Center on Earth's surface (43.564627,-116.220524) These values are Latitude and Longitude
        Radius: 15 Meters a Length on the surface of the earth

Circle 2:  Center on Earth's surface (43.564736,-116.219741) These values are Latitude and Longitude
        Radius: 15 Meters a Length on the surface of the earth
```

Expressed in Latitude and Longitude, where do these circles intersect?

I am unsure of the best method to find the closest results, accuracy within 2 meters should be alright.

Comment: and presumably also the radius of the Earth? or does that divide out of the answer?

Comment: What do you mean the circles' center? Edit for clarity: is a circle on the Earth a set of points on the surface of the earth equidistant from some point, that point being the "center"?

Comment: @Jay: What else could it be, given the wording of the question? It's certainly not a Great Circle.

Comment: @Seth: A minor technical point: is this radius measured along the surface of the earth, or as a distance in Euclidean 3-space? (Minor, because it doesn't affect the method used to solve the problem.)

Comment: What model are you using for the Earth? Sphere? Spheroid? Ellipsoid?

Comment: To clarify, this is two circles on earth, the centers are expressed in (Latitude,Longitude) and Radius in meters. I will know the Earth's mean equator length. I hope to have the intersections points in (Latitude,Longitude) format.

Comment: @Seth: you have clarified nothing. (i) Surface distance, or 3-space distance? (ii) "The earth's mean equator length"? Come on.

Comment: @TonyK (i) Surface distance, I have edited my question to include an example, I am very sorry if my lack of understanding is frustrating

Answer (score 2):

The centres of the circles are separated by 12.120247m North-South and by 63.0874577m East-West so that their separation comes to 64.2411683m. Since each circle has a radius of only 15m, THE CIRCLES DO NOT INTERSECT.